# Subquery returns more than 1 row (2 subqueries)

Tags: mysql

I have 2 different databases with different structures that I want to copy user register date from the first one to the second one.

My old database has `members` table with `member_id` and `added` columns.

My new database is a Wordpress database that has 2 tables in charge, `wp_users` table that has `user_registered` date (I want to update from the old database), the other table is `wp_usermeta` table which has the only connection between the two databases, as every Wordpress member has a meta value holding the `_member_id` from the old database.

So basically I will need to:

1- Update second database users table to change the register date for every user according to:

2- Result found in the query that is in searching for the date by member id that is found:

3- In user meta table value.

I need to do sub queries for this so that is what I came up with:

```
UPDATE `new_wp`.`wp_users` SET `user_registered` = 
(SELECT `added` FROM `old_script`.`members` WHERE `member_id` IN 
    (SELECT `meta_value` FROM `new_wp`.`wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_member_id'))
```

And of course, i got:

> ## 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

How can I do what I need to do please?

Comment: Yes it is, because I want to update all the users register date together, how can i return only 1 row? I tried to `LIMIT` the query but then all users now have the same register date, I want the date to change dynamically for every user according to the real `added` date in the old script.

Comment: Looks like you deleted your comment..

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I'm sorry, what is wrong with my question please?